# Player stops moving upon contact with a gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having my player constantly drop downwards on the screen and when the player interact with other gameobjects, I want to destroy those gameobjects and want the player to carry on dropping.

But the moment the player hits the other gameobject, the gameobject does gets destroyed but the player stops dropping. Please help advice what I am doing wrong.

```
//Script attached to player:

//x-axis movement speed
    public float playerMoveSpeed = 0.2f;
    //how much force to act against the gravity
    public float upForce = 9.0f;
    //horizontal control
    private float move;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //player left right x-axis movement control
        move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * playerMoveSpeed;
        transform.Translate(move, 0, 0);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //to fight against the gravity pull, slow it down
        rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * upForce);
    }


//Script attached to gameObject to be destroyed on contact with player

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        //as long as collide with player, kill object
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one should solve your problem, the second one might make your life easier :)

1.) Mark the objects as "Triggers" so that no real collision happens. That way your player should just fall through and keep its speed. You also need to use OnTriggerEnter instead of OnCollisionEnter

2.) If you dont really need "forces" but just want to move the player constantly you could just turn off gravity and set rigidbody.velocity manually like(i am assuming 2d here):

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    horizontalVelocity = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * playerMoveSpeed;

    rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(horizontalVelocity, verticalVelocity, 0.0f);
}
```

Just play around with values for verticalVelocity and horizontalVelocity untill it feels right.

Also note that if you move something in Update() you should probably multiply the translation with Time.deltaTime or your player will move faster on higher fps. FixedUpdate is called in fixed time intervalls so you dont need it there(thats why its called Fixed Update).